# What are the ways of creating table relationships in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database, ssms

I would like to know what are the ways of creating table relationships in SQL Server Management Studio

I know of 2 ways

- a sql script
- creating a DB diagram and creating the relationship there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also create relationships from the design view of a table. There is a "Relationships" button in the toolbar when you're in the design view. That's where I normally do it.

Answer (score 0):

You, can also make relationship between two tables by creating [Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) also.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Database Designer, click the row selector for one or more database columns that you want to relate to a column in another table.
2. Drag the selected column(s) to the related table.